# trying to copy pixal data from cpu to gpu using map every thing runs fine but the screen comes empty directx

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, directx

in my TextureHendler class, I create an empty texture using this

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc = { 0 };
textureDesc.Width = textureWidth;
textureDesc.Height = textureHeight;
textureDesc.Format = dxgiFormat;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
hr = m_deviceResource->GetD3DDevice()->CreateTexture2D(
        &textureDesc,
        nullptr,
        &texture);
```

and on runtime, I want to load data from CPU memory using the code below

```
Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ datapointer = GetPixelBytes();
static constexpr int BYTES_IN_RGBA_PIXEL = 4;
auto rowspan = BYTES_IN_RGBA_PIXEL * width;
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
auto device_context = m_deviceResource->GetD3DDeviceContext();
device_context->Map(m_texture->GetTexture2d(), 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &ms);
uint8_t* mappedData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(ms.pData);
for (int i = 0; i < datapointer->Length; i++)
{
    mappedData[i] = datapointer[i];
}
device_context->Unmap(m_texture->GetTexture2d(), 0);
```

everything runs fine but the output screen comes black

Update :

```
std::shared_ptr<TextureHendler> m_texture;
```

TextureHendler Holds

```
public:
ID3D11Texture2D* GetTexture2d() { return texture.Get(); }

private:
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;
```

and a load function which content is shown above

here are the sample code  https://github.com/AbhishekSharma-SEG/Demo_DXPlayer thanks for the help

Comment: What is m_texture? What is GetTexture2D? do you do any error check?

Comment: i have update the question

Comment: yes I check for errors, I am new to c++ and DirectX but yes I do error check using HResult for most of the functions if it fails I throw an error with the result

Comment: If you've checked Map gives a successful HRESULT (I guess it is otherwise you'd get a crash), then it probably means the texture's bits are 0 at the time you read it. Difficult to say w/o reproducing code. Also make sure you enabled debug layer. https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps it sometimes gives precious hints

Comment: I have tried out to check if the map function have any error and my debug layer is active and the map returned S_OK

Comment: here are the sample code  https://github.com/AbhishekSharma-SEG/Demo_DXPlayer thanks for the help

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. If you want to set the color of a texture, you can use a pixel shader, for example in DxComponent.h, line 96, replace `return importTextureColor(input.uv,sourceTexture,Sampler);` by `return float4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);` to color in red

Comment: actually, I changed that to make it available but in the future, there will be video frames that come and get updated on demand and I might be using FFmpeg and it's just to show that whenever I want to update texture data from CPU it does not and I removed all of the video part from it

Comment: ok there is something I found that I was creating a texture of format DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT While I was filling texture data as of DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM or DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT and the data that I was filling is not complete maybe that's why it's causing this issue but I am not sure because when I changed the format it started to fill up but something is still wrong in length because that calculated length must be equal to width * height * noOfBytePerPixel (4 in this case ) and still, I get some texture is missing Color most of the part get colored but not whole

Comment: I will update my finding in git